# How to resolve the error 'The name of the class AccordionGroup should end with the suffix Component'

Tags: css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, eslint

I got an error in angular2 and typescript.The name of the class AccordionGroup should end with the suffix Component.Its not stop the execution but it shows the error.I have implemented the accordion in angular2 and typescript.Here is my code.Please help me thanks in advance.

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'accordion',
      template:'<ng-content></ng-content>'
    })
    export class Accordion {
      groups: Array<AccordionGroup> = [];
      addGroup(group: AccordionGroup): void {
        this.groups.push(group);
      }
      closeOthers(openGroup: AccordionGroup): void {
        this.groups.forEach((group: AccordionGroup) => {
          if (group !== openGroup) {
            group.isOpen = false;
          }
        });
      }
      removeGroup(group: AccordionGroup): void {
        const index = this.groups.indexOf(group);
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.groups.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'accordion-group',
      template: `
        <div class="errors-cont" [ngClass]="{'panel-open': isOpen}">
            <div class="acc-header" (click)="toggleOpen($event)">
                <ng-content select="error-header"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <div class="acc-desc" [hidden]="!isOpen">
                <ng-content select="error-body"></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
      `
    })
    export class AccordionGroup implements OnDestroy {
      private _isOpen: boolean = false;
      @Input() heading: string;
      @Input()
      set isOpen(value: boolean) {
        this._isOpen = value;
        if (value) {
          this.accordion.closeOthers(this);
        }
      }
      get isOpen() {
        return this._isOpen;
      }
      constructor(private accordion: Accordion) {
        this.accordion.addGroup(this);
      }
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.accordion.removeGroup(this);
      }
      toggleOpen(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the styling guide here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-03

> Do append the symbol name with the conventional suffix (such as `Component`, `Directive`, `Module`, `Pipe`, or `Service`) for a thing of that type.

So if you change your `AccordionGroup` components name to `AccordionGroupComponent` the problem will be solved. This applies to all of your services and components.

Comment: @BenTaliadoros you mean besides using the suggested convention?

Comment: Yep. I found it:
tslint.json {
    "component-class-suffix": false
}

Answer (score 4):

***.eslintrc.json***

I have used this

```
 "rules": {
      
        "@angular-eslint/component-class-suffix": [
          "error",
          {
            "suffixes": [
              "Page",
              "Component"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: This is a rule added by default in new Ionic Angular starter projects (cf. .eslintrc.json generated by `ionic start test-eslint blank --type=angular`)